# all possible wordform completions of a (biomedical) word's stem

Tags: python, r, nlp, bioinformatics, text-mining

I'm familiar with word stemming and completion from the tm package in R.

I'm trying to come up with a quick and dirty method for finding all variants of a given word (within some corpus.)  For example, I'd like to get "leukocytes" and "leuckocytic" if my input is "leukocyte".

If I had to do it right now, I would probably just go with something like:

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
dictionary <- unique(unlist(lapply(crude, words)))
grep(pattern = LovinsStemmer("company"), 
    ignore.case = T, x = dictionary, value = T)
```

I used Lovins because Snowball's Porter doesn't seem to be aggressive enough.

I'm open to suggestions for other stemmers, scripting languages (Python?), or entirely different approaches.

Comment: Can you give an example where your proposed solution doesn't do what you want? And what yo do you mean by the Porter stemmer not being aggressive enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requires preprocessing your corpus. But once that is done it is a very quick dictionary lookup.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from stemming.porter2 import stem

with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()

stems = defaultdict(list)

for word in words:
    word_stem = stem(word)
    stems[word_stem].append(word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word = 'leukocyte'
    word_stem = stem(word)
    print(stems[word_stem])
```

For the `/usr/share/dict/words` corpus, this produces the result

```
['leukocyte', "leukocyte's", 'leukocytes']
```

It uses the [`stemming`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stemming/1.0) module that can be installed with

```
pip install stemming
```

Comment: Just getting back to this.  Running under Ubuntu 16.04.2, Python 2.7.12, this doesn't return anything for 'leukocyte'.  Maybe our words files are different?!  With 'jealous',  do get ['jealous', 'jealously', 'jealousness'].  With 'muscle' is get ['muscle', 'muscled', 'muscling'], but not 'muscular'.  So I guess this is a partial solution.  Maybe I'm expecting too much of inverse-stemming, especially with biomedical terms.  I can get plural and adjectival forms from http://uberon.github.io/